# What is `NoxConsole` `list` command output meaning?

Tags: android-emulator, emulators, noxplayer

From `Nox` documentation we know that there is following command:

`NoxConsole.exe list`

It lists existing emulators and some data about them. Example output follows:

> 0,nox,Business,0,0,0,-1,-1
>
> 1,Nox_1,Instagram,00210D2E,00371542,2732,23876

It is easy to understand that the 1st column is emulator index and the 3rd one is its name.

But what information does other column contain?

And why emulator which is currently running contains 7 columns, and stopped one contains 8 ones?

Comment: The [Yeshen FAQ](https://www.yeshen.com/faqs/r1xGelIqM) (Chinese) listed some of them, but it's still incomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the link provided by [Andrew T.](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/44325/andrew-t) from [Yeshen FAQ](https://www.yeshen.com/faqs/r1xGelIqM), and after some my own research, I can write the description of the `NoxConsole list` output columns:

1. The device index. You can use the index with `-index:` command line switch to refer the emulator.
2. The device virtual machine name. It is possible to use it to clone the emulator instance with `-clone:<nox_id>` command.
3. The device name. You can refer to the emulator with `-name:` command line switch with this value.
4. Top emulator window handle (HWND?) in hex format. If emulator is turned off, this value is `0`.
5. Toolbar windows handle (HWND?) in hex format. If emulator is turned off, this value is `0`.
6. This column is unclear; it is present when emulator is turned off only, and it is `0` always.
7. (6 if emulator is running) Emulator GUI (`Nox.exe`) process ID. If emulator is turned off, this value is `-1`.
8. (7 if emulator is running) Emulator virtual machine (`NoxVMHandle.exe`) process ID. If emulator is turned off, this value is `-1`.

Comment: Regarding 2, perhaps it can be used as the argument for the `-clone` parameter with `nox.exe` instead, based on [this article](https://www.bignox.com/blog/command-line-parameters-that-nox-app-player-supports/)?

Comment: very good answer